# Table to validate data inserted manually and give a message at the end

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to create a HTML table that will compare some numbers with some intervals and according to which interval the data is situated it will display a message at the end. the data is from polluted soil sample results and the result should tell me in which class the soil is situated. I have made the table but only the last cell is doing what I want. I could repeat the script an give each result to the right of each cell but in fact a just need an answer at the end. Can you help me build a global variable for my table?

Here is [what I have so far](http://pastebin.com/Bz5CM56R). The last cell is doing what I want.
The cells with text are there just for information purpose to give an general idea

I have 37 variables (analise results) that i have to compare with 3 intervals (FNADE Classe 1, 2 and 3). If just one of those variables is found in an interval it should display me the name of this interval (ex: FNADE Classe 1), the hierarchy being 3<2<1

Here is the code part, maybe it helps :

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
        var celula37 = parseInt(this.celula37.value,10);
        var text = "<b>Votre terre peut etre reçue dans une instalation : </b>";
        if (celula37 <= 399) text += "FNADE Classe 3";  
        else if (celula37 >= 400 && celula37 <= 1800) text += "FNADE Classe 2";  
        else if (celula37 >= 1801) text += "FNADE Classe 1";
        else text = "SVP inserez des donnes";
        document.getElementById("soilMessage").innerHTML=text;  
        return false; // cancel submit
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u add the code where you are having issues? You link has too much code...

Comment: You should really separate your styling from your html file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with groups of elements it's often easier to use a CSS class name so all of the elements can be treated as an array. It also helps you style things using CSS instead of repeating inline style statements.

```
<input type="text" class="cellData" name="celula37" id="celula37" value="" />
```

Then you can do this:

```
myData = document.getElementsByClassName('cellData')
var celula37;
for(var x = 0;x<myData.length;x++) {
    celula37 = parseInt(myData[x].value,10);
    ... your code ...
    document.getElementById('celula'+x).innerHTML = text;
    // note, arrays are zero-based, so you may need to tweak your IDs or 'x'


}
```

myData is then an array of all the inputs.

Then you can style things using CSS:

```
<style>
.cellData {
  border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
}

td {
  border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
}
</style>
```

Bon chance!

Comment: Merci @Diodeus, je vais essayer ce que tu as proposé, peut-être que ça marche

Comment: Demander si vous avez besoin de plus d'aide. En Englais SVP, for the sake of the audience :)